# Firefox mozilla binary. wayland, can not open system links Firefox is already running, but is not responding

Tags: firefox, synaptic

EDIT: This is a more specific problem than I thought, it affects the synaptic app but not much else.

There are many questions with this topic, but many of them are very old and probably not relevant to today's Ubuntu. I can not find any solution, even those reported to work on bugzilla (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1508803) and in other questions here.

I am on 22.10
I have mozilla binary installed for firefox, and no other firefox.

I have these envs:

tim@yellow:~$ more .pam_environment
MOZ_DBUS_REMOTE=1
MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1

also:

```
tim@yellow:~$ echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS 
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

and both are set correctly.
Firefox is therefore running with wayland.
It works great.

However, if I try to visit a link in synaptic,
I see this behaviour.

1. If firefox is not running, firefox opens the link
2. if firefox is running, there is a pause of a few seconds and then: "Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile."

I have inspected my menu structure with menulibre. There is only one desktop launcher for firefox. I install the mozilla binary following the exact instructions from mozilla, meaning the binary is in /opt

If I start a terminal and do:

```
firefox google.com
```

firefox launches.
If I make a new terminal and repeat that, it works: google.com opens in a new tab.

How can I fix this so that gtk apps can send links to the already running browser?

Update: This problem affects synaptic. But the Gnome software store is not affected; it works fine.